# Excel VBA cycle

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

How can I put this code in a cycle?
For example start the cylce in the A3 cell, end of the cycle in A100 cell.

```
Sub CenterImages()
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture 1")
            .Top = Range("A1").Top + (Range("A1").Height - .Height) / 2
            .Left = Range("A1").Left + (Range("A1").Width - .Width) / 2
        End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CenterImages()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To 100
        CenterImage i
    Next i
End Sub

Public Sub CenterImage(ByVal Index As Long)
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture " & Index)
        .Top = Range("A" & Index).Top + (Range("A" & Index).Height - .Height) / 2
        .Left = Range("A" & Index).Left + (Range("A" & Index).Width - .Width) / 2
    End With
End Sub
```

Make your code generic by using an `Index` then call your procedure in a loop from 3 to 100 specifying that index.